Downsizing AWS RDS database instance based on cloudwatch metrics
I have postgresql RDS db in AWS of size db.t3.large with 50gb vol. For cost reduction I am looking into reducing the instance size to db.t3.medium. Below are the cloudwatch metrics
Question 1: I  want to understand based on the below metrics if I can downsize instance to db.t3.medium without any issues.
Question 2: Can I simply modify/downsize the RDS instance from db.t3.large to db.t3.medium from AWS console without any data loss?
FreeStorageSpace - 49G
    
FreeableMemory - 5.3G
CPUUtilization - 3.4%
ReadThroughput - 10k-170k
NetworkReceiveThroughput - 6k   
NetworkTransmitThroughput- 250k
WriteIOPS- 10
ReadIOPS - 2
CPUCreditUsage - 0.403

